# Generate CROSS JOIN queries with dbplyr

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, dbplyr

Given 2 remote tables (simulated with `tbl_lazy` for this example)

```r
library("dplyr")
library("dbplyr")

t1 <- tbl_lazy(df = iris, src = dbplyr::simulate_mysql())
t2 <- tbl_lazy(df = mtcars, src = dbplyr::simulate_mysql())
```

How can I perform an *actual** cross join between t1 and t2 using **R** and **dbplyr**?

* i.e. using `CROSS JOIN` in the translated SQL query

Note that I know how to perform all the other types of joins, this is precisely about CROSS joins.

I am aware of the following trick:

```r
joined <- t1 %>%
  mutate(tmp = 1) %>%
  full_join(mutate(t2, tmp = 1), by = "tmp") %>%
  select(-tmp)
```

However

1. This is ugly (even if it could be hidden in a function)
2. I would like to take advantage of the highly optimised join capabilities of the DB, so I'd like to pass a real SQL `CROSS JOIN`. Using `show_query(joined)` shows that the generated SQL query uses `LEFT JOIN`.

Sadly, there is no `cross_join` operator in `dplyr` and `sql_join(t1, t2, type = "cross")` does not work either (not implemented for `tbl`s, works only on DB connections).

How can I generate an SQL `CROSS JOIN` with dbplyr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`dbplyr` NEWS file](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/f3529c3f4dc69c862384baf2d7bc387a5b89b83b/NEWS.md), since version 1.10, if you use a `full_join(..., by = character())`, it will "promote" the join to a cross join. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere else yet, but searching the [dbplyr Github repo for "cross"](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cross&type=) turned it up in both code and the NEWS file.

This syntax does not seem to work for local data frames, only via SQL.